# Simple Javascript or jQuery clearInterval problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I have gone through most of the code here and tried several ways to get clearInterval to work and for some reason it is just not working, although it is a basic and simple problem.

Here is the code and I want to know WHY it isn't working, not just get the code done for me.

```
var myTimer;

function startTimer() {
    myTimer = window.setInterval( function() {
        $('#randomImage').fadeTo('slow',0.0).addClass("changeBg_" + current);
        var current = Math.round(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        $('#randomImage').fadeTo('slow',1.0).addClass("changeBg_" + current);
    }, 5000);
};

function stopTimer(){
    window.clearInterval(myTimer);
    $('#randomImage').fadeTo('slow',0.0);

}
```

Thanks In Advance from a Newbie...

Comment: And what is it supposed to do? What do you mean by not working?

Comment: starTimer() rotates css classes randomly every 5 seconds and stopTimer() should clear the setInterval put in startTimer() but it does not stop the setInterval.

Comment: And are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else? Is `stopTimer` even being called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is fine, it works perfectly. It must be a problem with the code calling it. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NDpnQ/).

```
var myTimer;

function startTimer() {
    myTimer = window.setInterval( function() {
        $('#randomImage').fadeTo('slow',0.0).addClass("changeBg_" + current);
        var current = Math.round(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        $('#randomImage').fadeTo('slow',1.0).addClass("changeBg_" + current);
    }, 5000);
};

function stopTimer(){
    window.clearInterval(myTimer);
    $('#randomImage').fadeTo('slow',0.0);

}

startTimer();
$('#randomImage').click(function() { stopTimer(); });
```

Comment: Your right Jakub...I added $('#randomImage').click(function() { stopTimer(); }); as a call instead of the Div onclick="stopTimer()" and it worked... can you explain why please.

Comment: Update the question with the full source - it's hard to specluate about code you don't see.